# How to Get Files And Folders from Box.com by using "access_token" from OAuth2 from Java Application?

Tags: box-api

I have an "access_token" by requesting  "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token".
    By Using this "access_token" , I need to get the folders and files from box.com.
    For this , I am making a request like:
    https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/0?access_token=" + access_token1
    But I am getting Null as response.
    Some times, I am getting "In-sufficient Permission" error message. i.e 403 error.
    But , if send the same request via browser i am getting all the folders and files.
    Where Exactly I am getting problem?
    If you post related code, would be useful for me?
     Thanks
    Sarath.T

Answer (score 3):

Access tokens are sent as part of the authorization header, not as a GET query string parameter. The authorization header looks like this:

Authorization: Bearer

Check out the "Using Your Access Token with API V2" section on http://developers.box.com/oauth/